# Lightweight, small-memory-friendly job scheduler/control system for Linux?

Tags: linux, vps

I'm looking for a job control system for Linux.  Before you ask - quite aware of cron and at :-)

What I want is something where I can set time windows for jobs to run in, priorities, and some simple dependencies, maybe some retry rules.

In the Big Enterprise World this is AUTOSYS or Control-M.  There's also the [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Job_Scheduler), but it's Java-based and I suspect a memory hog.  Most of these jobs will be running on relatively small-memory VPS systems (256MB-2GB memory)

I search SuperUser.com but didn't see much in the way of answers...

[Scheduler for sequential jobs on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/528879/scheduler-for-sequential-jobs-on-linux)

https://superuser.com/questions/557501/choosing-job-scheduler-on-nix

Comment: might help to mention what distro - some init-replacements might be part of the solution here. Also, by 'windows' do you mean time windows?

Comment: Debian and CentOS at a minimum.  Edited to make time windows explicit.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at *Process Control Daemon* http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/pcd-process-control-daemon/

Comment: @sawdust: `pcd` reads like an incarnation of `daemontools` at al, thus more like a clever watchdog and not like a scheduler. am i wrong?

Comment: @raindog308: what is wrong about launching jobs with different priorities via different `nice`-levels? what is wrong with launching dependant jobs from withing one shell script? what is wrong with retrying a certain command from within a `while` loop inside a shell script?

Comment: I'm only aware of *PCD* and have never used it.  Hence I offered it as a comment rather than an answer.  You'll have to evaluate *PCD* yourself to see if it meets all your requirements.

Comment: You should be able to do this with some simple scripting combined with `at` and/or `cron`. Why don't you give us a specific example and see what we can come up with?

Answer (score 0):

I may advice you to try TlosLite, it is simple, light-weight and java based web enabled scheduler free to 10 jobs.